# Change the colour of the upper blue horizontal bar

Tags: 2013, master-page, css

[image]Can I change the default blue bar and remove the words SharePoint from the top blue bar?

Masterpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by changing the CSS for that control. The control is implemented differently in On Premise than O365, so here's how to change it in both scenarios:

Office 365:

```
.o365cs-base.o365cst .o365cs-topnavBGColor, .o365cs-base.o365cst .o365cs-topnavLinkBackground{
background-color: red; 
}
```

This is to change it to red color for example.

In an on premise environment:

```
#suiteBarLeft{
 background-color: red; 
}
```

Comment: /* Top bar re colour */
#suiteBarLeft{
 background-color: #123274; 
}
 But this change isn't seen when adding a new list item.

Comment: Hi Mike, can you add a screenshot so I can see what you mean exactly?

Comment: Screen shot added.  Also is it possible to remove the test Sahrepoint in CSS?

Comment: Hi Mike, the first issue seems weird, can you try with `background-color: red !important; `. The second issue you can solve it by using this code: `.ms-corebrandingText{display: none; }  `

Comment: This is the code I pasted in #suiteBarLeft{
 background-color: #123274 !important;
}


.ms-corebrandingText{display: none; } It didn't remove Sharepoint from the title or re colour the form bar.

Answer (score 0):

It is called the suitebar. If u are on premise you can change it. It is a web application property you can e.g set it with powershell as described here. http://sharepointryan.com/2013/04/16/customizing-the-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar-branding-using-powershell/

In SharePoint online you shouldn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this style in either your master page or a css file:

```
div#suiteBarLeft{
   background-color: red;
}
```

In this example, the top blue color will be changed to red, you can change it to any color you want.